# Put tags around part of string in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I get my strings out of a `MySQL` database. An example string:

```
'
{something}Lorem ipsum{/something} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; 
{blablabla}Illa tamen simplicia{blablabla}, vestra versuta.
Non semper, inquam; Sed mehercule pergrata mihi oratio tua. 
Stoici scilicet. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti;
'
```

In php, I assign the string to a Smarty variable like this:

```
$smarty->assign('homePageText', $string);
```

Now, I want to be able to do something like this in the template:

```
{$homePageText}
  {something}
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/" class="foo">{$}</a>
  {/something}
  {blablabla}
    <b class="bar"><i>{$}</i></b>
  {/blablabla}
{/$homePageText}
```

So the string will change into this:

```
'
<a href="http://www.domain.com/" class="foo">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; 
<b class="bar"><i>Illa tamen simplicia</i></b>, vestra versuta.
Non semper, inquam; Sed mehercule pergrata mihi oratio tua. 
Stoici scilicet. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti;
'
```

So that you can put tags around parts of a variable in a Smarty template. Is there already a function like this in Smarty 3.0? Or how can I build this into smarty in php 5.4? I want as little as possible php code in my templates. Also, the `{something}<tag>{$}</tag>{/something}` part shouldn't be in the php files since there will be multiple templates per page

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to achieve from this question. Please explain it in details. Also `$smarty->assign('homePageText');` is incorrect because you don't set here any value.

Comment: You could use custom template resources ( http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.custom.tpl ) in combination with template inheritance ( http://www.smarty.net/inheritance )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a plugin to Smarty:

```
class SmartyPlugins {

    public static function addTags($string, $search, $openingTag, $closingTag) {
        return str_replace(
            '{/' . $search . '}', 
            $closingTag, 
            str_replace(
                '{' . $search . '}', 
                $openingTag, 
                $string
            )
        );
    }
}

//register the plugin
$smarty->registerPlugin('modifier', 'addTags', array('SmartyPlugins', 'addTags'));
```

Now I can do this in the template:

```
{$var|addTags:'a':'<a href="http://domain.com">':'</a>'} //changes "Test {a}blablabla{/a} something" to "Test <a href="http://domain.com">blablabla</a> something"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple `replace` modificator in similar settings. But I assume that this approach is neither very elegant nor flexible. Anyway, the string in my Database would look like this:

```
'%something1%Lorem ipsum%something2% dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; 
%blablabla1%Illa tamen simplicia%blablabla2%, vestra versuta.
Non semper, inquam; Sed mehercule pergrata mihi oratio tua. 
Stoici scilicet. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti;'
```

And the Code in the Template would look this way (remove the line breaks!):

```
{$homePageText|replace:'%something1%':'<a href="http://www.domain.com/" class="foo">'
    |replace:'%something2%':'</a>'
    |replace:'%blablabla1%':'<b class="bar"><i>'
    |replace:'%blablabla2%':'</i></b>'
}
```

I use this in a scenario, where the translations come from a database table, but some HTML markup or URLs are hard coded in the templates.

btw: You could use `regex_replace` to insert the opening and closing tag in one step, but it doesnt really improve the readability...

```
|regex_replace:'/%something1%(.*)%something2%/':'<a href="http://www.domain.com/" class="foo">\\1</a>'
```

Comment: Unfortunatly you have to strip the line breaks, I added for better readability. Sorry; didn't tested it.